# ContextMenuOpening when opening a ContextMenu from a ListViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, events, contextmenu

I have a *ListView* with some data and an *ItemContainerStyle* to bind the *ContextMenu* to every item (so it only appears when clicking on an item in the *ListView*)
I've got the *ContextMenu* defined in *ListView.Resources*. How do I properly fire the *ContextMenuOpening* event and then access the *ContextMenu* in the *ContextMenuEventArgs* in said event?

```
ListView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14">
              //Rest of the ContextMenu
                <MenuItem Header="Custom Actions">

                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Right now, I tried to have an *Event Setter* in the style,

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ItemContextMenu}" />
                <EventSetter Event="ContextMenuOpening" Handler="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening" />
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

but this triggers a *NullPointerException* here in the C#-Code (which is basically copied from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-handle-the-contextmenuopening-event)

```
private void ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        ContextMenu cm = fe.ContextMenu;

        List<MenuItem> customActions = new List<MenuItem>();


        customActions.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "First Thing"});
        customActions.Add(new MenuItem {Header = "Second Thing"});


        foreach (MenuItem mi in cm.Items) // here is the NullPointerException
        {
            if((String)mi.Header == "Custom Actions")
            {
                foreach(MenuItem cmi in customActions)
                {
                    mi.Items.Add(cmi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I access the *ContextMenu* and modify it before opening?

Comment: I've tested your code and it works just fine.

Comment: @Mitya ... really? I got it to work when using lvi = sender as ListViewItem and cm = lvi.ContextMenu